# Adding a new record to a relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to learn more about creating "advanced" databases, so my project is to keep track of the wins and losses at a website called SaltyBet.  Bots fight against each other and people bet on the outcome.  I want to create a database for myself to keep track of each match, where I enter in the values manually.

I have 2 tables:

`chars` with just an "ID" field and a "name" (unique) field, and

`matches` with "ID", "player1", "player2", "winner", and "odds".

The way I want it to work is if I go to insert a row into `matches`, it will create the appropriate character in the `chars` database, if it doesn't already exist.

I have the following relationships set up within PHPMyAdmin:

[image: Relationships]

Creating this form in the "Insert" view:

[image: Insert view]

This works fine - as long as I have already entered in both characters in the `chars` table.  However, there often isn't enough time to go through 3 different views to create the appropriate characters in the `chars` table to then use in the `matches` table.  I had the idea to create a trigger, which inserts the characters if they don't exist, but AFAIK I cannot maintain the relationship between the two tables because I cannot enter a new one in `matches`.

Is there any way I can easily approach this without writing a form in PHP?  I'd rather learn how to do it the "proper" way instead of relying on the simple MySQL commands I learned years ago and never expanded on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that if you want to use a trigger that creates the row in chars after an insert in matches, it won't work because the insert itself will give a problem.

I don't see how you can do it without coding an application that would first verify in chars whether the row exists, insert it if needed, then insert into matches.

Comment: That seems to be the only way to go, but it's nice to hear a second opinion.  Thank you very much!